# Rails Many to Many with common children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Within my sample application, I have

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

Database model

- Physicians: id, name
- Appointments: id, date_time, physician_id, patient_id
- Patients: id, name

Across a week, I a doctor has appointments to see 20 patients including one patient twice. For `doc = Physician.first`, if I look at the patients list `doc.patients` I get a list of patients, one for each appointment, including one patient listed twice. I just want a list of unique patients. I know that `doc.patients.uniq` will get me a list of unique patients, but I do not understand why this isn't what is returned in the first place.

I'd be grateful for any explanation of why this works this way and whether actually my model should be structured differently.

Comment: add also your Physician model, please

Comment: @coorasse sorry, I'd missed marking the Physician as code.

Comment: When you use the :through association then what happens is for each entry a relevant object is returned if the mapping is valid. You can read more about it here.

Comment: @Egalitarian thanks, I think you missed the link though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you can do

`has_many :patients, -> { uniq }, through: :appointments`

The uniq scope needs to passed as the second argument to has_many. (Thanks to coorasse for the updated syntax.)

You are getting duplicates because rails picks up all the patient associations made through appointments, so if a patient has more than one appointment, that's more than one record, and rails will pick up all records. Adding :uniq tells SQL to get unique records.

Comment: Note however that in Rails 4, this behaviour has been deprecated in favour of scoping: `has_many :patients, ->{ uniq }, :through => :appointments`

Comment: Thanks Richbits, I wasn't aware of the new syntax. I've approved an edit from coorasse.